# Изменения без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим у меня есть файл `test.html`

А в нём такой `html` код:

```
<body>
   <div>Текст</div>
</body>
```

Открываю его в нестандартном браузере (своё приложение) и вижу `Текст`.

В текстовом редакторе я могу изменять `html` код и сохранять.

А могу ли я без перезагрузки браузера - увидеть изменения после сохранения файла ?

Comment: У вас файл лежит локально или на сервере?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov локально

Comment: Никак. Только если будете по таймеру сами перезагружать страницу

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а всякие штуки типа [Live Edit в WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-edit.html) не считаются?

Comment: @diraria, WebStorm запускает свой локальный сервер, и таки да, может перезагружать страницу при изменении

Comment: @Nick ну и разве ТС где-нибудь написал, что это ему не подходит?

Comment: Для этого существует разного рода `gulp webpack и т.д.и т.п.`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov а в случае, если будет на сервере, что необходимо делать ?

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, для новичка самым простым и удобным способом будет установить это популярное расширение.

[Вот](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei) для хрома.

Если вы хотите использовать его с локальными файлами, обязательно установите флажок "Разрешить доступ к файлам" в Инструменты > Расширения > LiveReload после установки.

Как запустить:

1. Убедитесь, что LiveReload запущен
2. Нажмите кнопку панели инструментов LiveReload, чтобы включить или отключить LiveReload.

Кнопка панели инструментов LiveReload находится на главной панели инструментов в Chrome и Safari и на панели инструментов надстройки в Firefox (внизу).

Значок указывает состояние LiveReload текущей вкладки (недоступно/отключено/включено/идет подключение/идет отключение).

Если вы используете такие вещи, как CoffeeScript, SASS или LESS (и вы должны!), LiveReload скомпилирует их все для вас. Просто включите его; LiveReload управляется двумя основными флажками, поэтому вы не заблудитесь.